# What makes React.memo unreliable for preventing renders?

Tags: reactjs

In the [documentation for React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), it says:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

I don't really understand this warning. Why can it not be relied on? How is it an optimization if it doesn't necessarily prevent renders?

I wish they had gone more into depth here, but since they didn't, can someone elaborate on this? As is, I feel reluctant to use it at all because this warning makes its behavior seem very unclear.

Comment: I believe you can't 100% rely on it because React can decide to release the memory which was allocated to store the rendered result (for some memory optimization reasons maybe).

Comment: Same confusion+1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps, we should consider this quote from official docs about the similar [`useMemo` function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.**
>
> In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized
>   values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for
>   offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without
>   useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.

I believe the same could apply to `React.memo` and to `useCallback` hooks so you can't 100% rely on that React won't "forget" some memorized prop to free some memory.

Comment: Supposing you do want a semantic guarantee, what should you do? Change how the render code is written?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky I believe you can write your own custom hook with the dependable memoization (not clearable during the life cycle of a component)

Comment: Thank you. I posted this question here if you want to answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977693/how-do-i-use-react-memo-or-usememo-with-a-semantic-guarantee

Answer (score 2):

> If the Parent component is passing a function (specifically, a
>   function that updates the state of the Parent) down to the Child
>   component, only using React.memo will not work. The function in the
>   Parent component will need to be wrapped with the useCallback hook.
>   This is because the function will be "re-rendered" every time the
>   Parent re-renders, so the Child will always consider that function a
>   new prop.

Read more on this [here](https://codebushi.com/react-component-optimization/)

Here is another interesting discussion I found regarding [React.memo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14463)

Also `React.memo` is for functional components what `React.PureComponent` is for class components.

`PureComponent` handles `shouldComponentUpdate` method by default (shallow comparison).

`shouldComponentUpdate` basically tells react whether reconciliation is needed or not. If it is `true` then react compares the `newly returned element with the previously rendered one` using its diffing algorithm and based on the comparison it will update the DOM. There may be a case when the component was reconciled but rendered react elements were same so no DOM changes happened.

To get a clear picture for above have a look at this [diagram](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action)

I think basis on above we can say that `React.memo` also tells us whether `render` cycle should run for a component. Actual DOM changes depends upon the diffing algorithm that react does to update the DOM.

Comment: I don't think that this is what the question is about. It's expected for React.memo to re-render the component when it receives a new prop (a new function in your example), but the question points (well, the official docs points) that even if all props are equal you can't rely that there won't be a re-render.

Comment: No, what that means is, even if the function is same and the parent re-renders, for the child that function will be a new prop.

And the official docs are unclear on the re-rendering part. They do not say that there will or will not be a re-render given the same props.

Comment: I think what you say about a new prop for a child is an obvious thing and doesn't raise a question (at least I believe this particular question is not about it). During render parent creates a new function of course so you need to wrap it in `useCallback` to memorize it. However, React docs do say that you shouldn't rely on `useMemo` and therefore I believe on `useCallback` since it's just a performance optimization ([docs ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo))

Comment: Well, the scenario that I mentioned was not an obvious thing to me. What you have shared in regards to `useMemo` makes sense if we are talking about `useMemo`. Not sure if we can translate the same concept to `React.memo`.