# How do I use React.memo or useMemo with a semantic guarantee?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The documentation for `useMemo` says:

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some
>   previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g.
>   to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it
>   still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance

`React.memo` and `shouldComponentUpdate` have similar warnings.

I have a case, however, where I want a functional component not to update under certain conditions. I am looking for memo-like functionality not for performance, but for the semantic guarantee of there being no update given some conditions. How do I address this issue?

Comment: `where I want a component not to update under certain conditions` ? [`should component update`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) isn't serving your purpose ?

Comment: Could you perhaps store the values you want to memoize in a useRef?

Comment: @CodeManiac I have a functional component. Thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: @WillJenkins yeah that's what I was thinking, but it's not really possible/very difficult because I'm working with a deep Relay-driven tree of components that independently subscribe to data. I would be much, much simpler to memo.

Comment: @CodeManiac do you know whether `shouldComponentUpdate()` has this property?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky you can stop rendering of component based on your needs through this , and docs has good notes on it, read on the link i have added in first comments it show even alternatives too

Comment: @CodeManiac I clicked through to the docs for `shouldComponetUpdate` and they say the same thing as for the memo methods: "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a rendering, as this can lead to bugs."

Comment: @WillJenkins I simplified my components to enable the solution you suggest. That's probably the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the values you need to memoize in a `useRef()`

Comment: In my case, I mediated the state with `useState`, but whether `useRef` or `useState` is used depends on one's specific circumstances.

Comment: hmm but if your  value must be recomputed if some dependency changes, then `useRef` won't help probably..?

Comment: @g-moniava yep, if you want a re-render, then `useState`

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky That was not my point, I asked that because useRef doesn't seem to solve the problem of this question completely, does it? When you store something in useRef it stays like that, if you don't reassign it. So is it really a replacement of useMemo as the question was asking?