# React memoized component rerenders without props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have trouble with memoizing my component.

```
const Miscellaneous = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch<DispFn>();

    const brokers = useSelector(getSettingsMiscBrokers);
    const charterers = useSelector(getSettingsMiscCharterers);

    if (window.charterers) {
        console.log(window.charterers === charterers, 'check equality charterers');
    } else {
        window.charterers = charterers;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchBrokersList());
    }, []);

    return (
        <AclShowSectionWrapper sectionName={CHARTER_SETTINGS}>
            <div className="fb" style={{ padding: '1rem 2rem 2rem 2rem' }}>
                <Row className="bigHorizontalScroll" grow noWrap>
                    <Col {...colGrid}>
                        <Charterers charterers={charterers} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col {...colGrid}>
                        <Brokers brokers={brokers} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </AclShowSectionWrapper>
    );
};

export const Charterers = React.memo((props: IProps) => {
    console.log('charterers');
    return (
        <div>{*some stuff here*}</div>
    );
});
```

An this is the selector function for charterers

```
 export const getSettingsMiscCharterers = createSelector(
  [(state: AppState) => state.shared.data.charterers],
  charterers => {
    if (!charterers || !charterers.payload) {
      return {
        ...charterers,
        payload: [],
        status: FETCH_STATUS.inProgress
      };
    }
    return charterers;
  }
);
```

So the problem is, that when I make a change in brokers table and that causes store changes only in brokers part, and this statement **console.log(window.charterers === charterers, 'check equality charterers');** always is true, charterers get rendered every time.

Maybe I am missing something important here?

Comment: I posted an answer illustrating the main issue when working with React.memo. For further debugging, if that doesn't solve your issue; please provide your `getSettingsMiscCharterers` selector

Comment: Just saw it. please ignore my previous comment

Comment: Here is an answer which I wrote on `React.memo` some time ago.
It may help you in debugging your problem. TLDR is `react.memo
` can't be relied on for preventing re-renders https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349504/what-makes-react-memo-unreliable-for-preventing-renders/55349966#55349966

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't provide any function to test on the props equality; so the `shallow` comparison is executed.

Thus, if your `selector` returns a new array/object (I presume it's the case especially if you are using array/object destructing to populate the selectors return value); the shallow equality will always return false; and then the component will re-render.

I recommend using [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) from `lodash` to test on the equality

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';
Const MemoizedComponent = React.memo(Component, isEqual);
```

**edit**:

You are using the selector like this: `useSelector(selectorCreator)`.

It should be `useSelector(selectorCreator())`

quoted from [the docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors)

> When using useSelector with an inline selector as shown above, a new
>   instance of the selector is created whenever the component is
>   rendered.

Besides, `createSelector` calls `createSelectorCreator` with the selector; that, returns a new function each time, that, also, calls the function with a new function every time

```
export const createSelector = /* #__PURE__ */ createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize)
export function createSelectorCreator(memoize, ...memoizeOptions) {
  return (...funcs) => {
    let recomputations = 0
    const resultFunc = funcs.pop()
    const dependencies = getDependencies(funcs)

    const memoizedResultFunc = memoize(
      function () {
        recomputations++
        // apply arguments instead of spreading for performance.
        return resultFunc.apply(null, arguments)
      },
      ...memoizeOptions
    )
```

You can see the [concrete implementation in github](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/0c2573987627d620ac5c6d1469eb222b26a867e7/src/index.js#L52)

Comment: Actually no, because I use reselect in this case and in that case, it always returns the same object (eg. the reference).
window.charterers === charterers  will be true

Comment: Just saw also that you are using useSelector like this: `useSelector(selectorCreator)`; I think it is `useSelector(selectorCreator())`. updating my answer; but the shallow equality answer stays valid in case someone misses it

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector-examples 
Check this link please , you can use valid usage of reselect with useSelector

Comment: A function invokation that returns a function will always creates a new function (a new reference each time). I ve already faced that issue.

Comment: or use the second parameter (equality func)

Comment: please take a look here https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors

Comment: I ave used it the same way as described in react-redux.js.org. I can't understand your opinion